# Images are not loading all of a sudden in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to build a basic blog using django framework. In the posts, i have image field in the Post model. First few posts were added properly. But after i added pagination, the images are not being loaded. Whatever image i add, it is not loading on the screen.

models.py:

```
    import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models



class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT);
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_image(self):
        return os.path.join('/media', self.poster.name)
```

views.py:

```
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    posts_list = Post.objects.filter(status='published')
    paginator = Paginator(posts_list, 2)  # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',{'page':page,'posts':posts})
```

Template:

```
    {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

          <h1 class="my-4">BlogSpot
            <small>Find Everything</small>
          </h1>
{% for post in posts %}
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">

        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
          <!-- Blog Post -->
          <div class="card mb-2">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.get_absolute_image }}" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
              <p class="card-text"></p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
              {{ post.publish }} by {{post.author}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>

{% endfor %}
<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
{% if posts.has_previous %}
<a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
{% endif %}
<span class="current">
Page {{ posts.number }} of {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}.
</span>
{% if posts.has_next %}
<a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
{% endif %}
</span>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

These are the files I have used. All of a sudden, when i add the new posts, images are not being loaded. How to solve this?

Comment: Does the media directory contains the images?

Comment: yes, every image is being stored there.

Comment: What happens if you look at the rendered HTML and try to fetch the image src?

Comment: Even in the log it is not displaying any 404 error.

Comment: I mean that you should inspect the rendered HTML of the blogs, and then open the URL in the browser of the image. Typically this provides more debug info,

Comment: I inspected the element, the image is being loaded but not being shown.

Comment: I think the problem is with your urls.py have add this to url patterns - + static(MEDIA_URL, document_root=MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: check if you are getting the correct image path

Comment: The image is path is also correct. it is fetching from the correct location i.e media folder